# What does Kirov airship captain meant when saying "Bearing set"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is Kirov airship from c&c video game:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz33m.png

And it captain says: "Bearing set" when ordered to move. I dont understand what it means. In google or translator it is wheel bearing makes no sence.

Answer (score 1):

[Definition of "bearing" from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bearing):

> the situation or horizontal direction of one point with respect to another or to the compass

[Definition of "set" from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set):

> to adjust (a device and especially a measuring device) to a desired position

(Actually, M-W's definition is lacking. In addition to "setting" a device, one can also "set" a quantity that a device measures: a time, a temperature, a bearing, etc.)

In this case, "set" is a past participle. The speaker means that the bearing is (has been) set.